# How to mask phone number as 123-456-7890?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

In my database I have phone number as 123-456-7890 and 1234567890, Is there any way to format display in as `123-456-7890` format in my textbox

In my view I have phone textbox as

```
 <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" readonly class="form-control" id="PhoneNumber" placeholder="">
```

I need to format all phone number as `123-456-7890`

i tried:

```
function formatPhoneNumber(txt) {
  if (String(txt)[3] != "-") {
    txt = "" + txt.slice(0, 3) + "-" + txt.slice(3, 6) + "-" + txt.slice(6);
  }
  return txt;
}
```

and in my text box

```
<input asp-for="PhoneNumber"  type="tel" readonly pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" onchange="formatPhoneNumber(this)" class="form-control fa-mask" id="PhoneNumber" placeholder="">
```

Comment: BTW: Here in Germany, we [format them differently](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufnummer#Schreibweisen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo to show how to bind data of Model with format 111-111-1111,and when change the input with the format 111-111-1111.
Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            TestReadOnly t = new TestReadOnly { PhoneNumber = "1231231234" };
            return View(t);
        }
```

View:

```
    @model TestReadOnly
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
<input asp-for="PhoneNumber" type="tel" aria-label="Please enter your phone number" placeholder="ex. 111-111-1111" onchange="change()">
@section scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //bind the data from Model with format 111-111-1111
            let txt = JSON.stringify(@Model.PhoneNumber);
            if (String(txt)[3] != "-") {
                txt = '' + txt.substring(0, 3) + "-" + txt.substring(3, 6) + "-" + txt.substring(6);
            }
            $('[type="tel"]').val(txt); 
        })
    //when change the input value,format 111-111-1111    
    function phoneMask() {
        var num = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
        $(this).val(num.substring(0, 3) +'-'+  num.substring(3, 6) + '-' + num.substring(6, 10));
    }
    $('[type="tel"]').keyup(phoneMask);
    </script>
}
```

result：
[image]

Comment: anyways to replace on change to on page load?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the function you can write `<script>formatPhoneNumber("1234567890")</script>` after the `input` tag.

note that if you write `(this)` in the `input`, the parameter is the element itself (in this case, the `input`).

So, if you write the `(this)`, just change the function a little:

```
function formatPhoneNumber(el)
{
  let txt = el.value; // add this line
  if (String(txt)[3] != "-")
  {
    txt = '' + txt.slice(0, 3) + "-" + txt.slice(3, 6) + "-" + txt.slice(6);
  }
  //return txt // delete this line
  el.value = txt // add this line instead
}
```

If you don't call the functio via the `input` (which means you write `<script>formatPhoneNumber(parameter)</script>`), the parameter will be `document.getElementById("PhoneNumber")`.

Comment: Thank you! Is this js function, can you show me the full code how can i apply that phone number textbox? sorry i am a newbie :)

Comment: Yes, it is a javascript function. There is no full code, this is only makes a string of `1234567890` to `123-456-7890`. If you want to use the string in a different tag you should do: `document.getElemetById("id_name")` and then `.value` or `.innerHTML` (depends on the tag), then `=`, and then the string